# Can't access to Wordpress site on localhost via mobile browser (Chrome devtools - remote devices)

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I can't access to wordpress site on localhost from mobile browser.

I have connected my phone to the Chrome remote devices and I can access to the XAMPP dashboard

```
localhost:8080/dashboard
```

[image: localhost:8080/dashboard screenshot]

but when I am trying to do the same with a wordpress site which stored in folder `htdocs/mysite` in this case the mobile browser can't reach it (but desktop browser can when simply type `localhost/mysite` without any ports).

And in addition the URL in mobile browser is being overridden from `localhost:8080/mysite` to `localhost/mysite`

[image: localhost/mysite screenshot]

Note: I can access all static websites or websites with custom CMS from mobile browser. But there is an issue with wordpress CMS.

Here is a standard .htaccess from WP

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried a various examples to solve my problem. 
but unsuccessfully. For example if I type `127.0.0.1:8080/mysite` in mobile browser then there is a blank page and bunch of errors in the devtools console (for all resources: css, js etc.):

```
GET http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Appreciate any hints

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your site url and home value in wp_options in phpmyadmin from 'localhost' to your accessing Url. For me i am accessing my localhost from Url '192.168.1.4' and it redirects me to localhost if this is the case.

I edited my site url and home url from 'http://localhost/mysite' to 'http://192.168.1.4/mysite'. in your case you can edit like 'http://localhost:8080/mysite'.