# Accessing local installed Wordpress from a mobile device in the same network

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

I have set up the latest Wordpress version 5.3.2 on my local machine by using XAMPP 3.2.4.
Since I want to check out my homepage also on a mobile device (not only an emulator on my desktop) I tried to access it from my phone. I always get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when I try to call it with "http://192.168.0.170/wordpress". This is the IP of my notebook where XAMPP is running.

Interesting thing to add: It works without issues from another notebook in the same network. What I have seen is, that the mobile phone redirects from the IP address to "localhost/wordpress" while the notebooks do not redirect.

Now, I am aware that this is not a new problem and I have read most likely all posts on this topic in the internet. What did I already tried and changed in order to get it running:

- Add an entry in the Firewall settings to allow connections on port 80
- Change the site URL and home URL in the wordpress settings to the local IP

There are multiple suggestions to change settings in the Apache config files from XAMPP. I did not do any changes there as the code which is proposed to be changed cannot be found in the files.

Do you have any idea why it could not work on a mobile device while it does work from another notebook?

Thank you very much!

Regards,
Philip

Comment: One small thing to check, ensure your phone is on the wifi from a router that can see the same network.  On the server side of things, the same URL will work no matter who it is coming from, since you have already tested that with the notebook, look next to the network.

Comment: Hi Katie, Thanks for the answer! I checked that, I can access the root of localhost (XAMPP starting page) from my phone. Only access to Wordpress sub directory does not work...

Comment: Then it might be the wordpress redirect, try this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807172/cant-access-to-wordpress-site-on-localhost-via-mobile-browser-chrome-devtools

Comment: As written above, I already changed the site url and home url to the IP address of the notebook as it is suggested in the answer to the linked post...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation. This is what I did to solve it:

1. Change the `WP_SITEURL` constant in 'wp-config.php':
   `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://192.168.0.170/' );`
2. In your wordpress dashboard, also change the 'Site Address (URL)' to the same value.